# How to boot CentOS in multiuser mode without asking for password?

Tags: centos, boot, login

I have run into some trouble and when I enter correct password for "root" in multi user mode; it is not logging in.

When I executed the command `whoami` or `passwd root`, it was throwing a error saying that, `root user not found`, or some invalid user.

I wanted to check this problem in single user mode. In single user mode, it's working fine.

In another words, can I go to console without password in multiuser mode ?

Comment: I dont know, Why is it down voted ? SE has become tough place to post your question.

Answer (score 0):

Though the question was down voted. I want to write the answer here in detail, so that it helps someone.

OS: Centos, cPanel server

Issues:

1. Most of the services were not running. All the services(such as http, mysql, exim, csf were failing), throwing error such as user "nobody", "mysql" is not found.
2. When running a command "passwd root", thrown error unknown user root.
3. System was booting in a single user mode and not in multi user mode
4. Instead of user name when we list(ls -l) the file, it used to display only the UID

the solution to the problem is,

The / was chmod-ed to 400 by someone accidentally. Everything started working fine, once we run the command "chmod 755 /"

Comment: `chmod 755 /` is definitely not a good way to fix this,... at **least** switch /tmp back with `chmod 1777 /tmp`! If, however, the command that was actually ran on the machine was `chmod -R 400 /` then you should seriously consider reinstalling.